# Counts of re-purchase same product by the same customer in certain days or within certain duration days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to have the counts of re-purchase same product by the same customer in tow scenarios: in certain days and within certain duration.

Here is the sample data:

```
create table tbl
(
  Customer  varchar(5),
  StartDay date,
  EndDay date,
  Product  varchar(5),
  Cost  decimal(10,2)
);

insert into tbl values 
('A',       '1/1/2019',      '1/4/2019',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('B',       '2/4/2021',      '2/7/2021',      'Hat',          10.00),
('A',       '1/7/2019',      '1/8/2019',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('B',       '5/8/2018',      '5/9/2018',      'Shoe',         10.00),
('A',       '2/1/2019',      '2/3/2019',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('C',       '6/6/2020',      '6/6/2020',      'Hat',         10.00),
('C',       '11/9/2021',     '12/9/2021',     'Cloth',       10.00),
('A',       '3/3/2019',      '3/17/2019',     'Cloth',        10.00),
('C',       '7/8/2020',      '7/12/2020',      'Hat',         10.00),
('E',       '7/2/2020',      '9/1/2020',      'Hat',        10.00),
('A',       '3/3/2019',      '3/7/2019',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('A',       '7/5/2022',      '7/9/2022',      'Hat',       10.00),
('C',       '6/6/2020',      '6/8/2020',      'Shoe',        10.00),
('B',       '8/2/2018',      '8/9/2018',      'Shoe',         10.00),
('A',       '1/1/2019',      '1/11/2019',     'Cloth',        10.00),
('E',       '9/3/2020',      '10/1/2020',      'Hat',        10.00),
('E',       '7/2/2020',      '7/8/2020',      'Shoe',       10.00);
```

Duration is the difference between the last EndDay and the next StartDay for same customer purchasing same product.

For example:

For customer A, the EndDay at the first time he purchased "Shoe" was '1/4/2019.  And the StartDay at the second time he purchased the 'shoe' was '1/7/2019'. So the duration was within 30 days.

For customer B, the EndDay at the first time he purchased "Shoe" was '5/8/2018.  And the StartDay at the second time he purchased the 'shoe' was '8/2/201'. So the duration was within 60 - 90 days.

Expected outcome for first scenario:
[image]

Expected outcome for second scenario:
[image: s]

Thank you very much for your help in advance!!

Comment: I can't relate the dates in the results with the sample data. Also, what is the difference between the two scenarios?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hi GMB, each row as a new start. For first scenario,  just count it as long as the duration falls in the certain days, let's say 30 days or 60 days. For second scenario, only count when the duration falls in the range, such as 30 - 60 days, or 60 - 90 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 1:

```
select  Customer    
       ,StartDay    
       ,EndDay  
       ,Product 
       ,Cost
       ,[0]                  as '0-30 days'
       ,[0] + [1]            as '0-60 days'
       ,[0] + [1] + [2]      as '0-90 days'
       ,[0] + [1] + [2]+ [3] as 'total'
from
(
select  t.Customer
       ,t.StartDay
       ,t.EndDay
       ,t.Product
       ,t.Cost
       ,case when (datediff(day, t.EndDay, t2.StartDay)-1)/30 > 3 then 3 else (datediff(day, t.EndDay, t2.StartDay)-1)/30 end as dd
from    t left join t t2 on  t2.Customer = t.Customer 
                         and t2.Product = t.Product
                         and t2.StartDay > t.EndDay
) t
pivot(count(dd) for dd in([0],[1],[2],[3])) p
order by Customer, Product, StartDay
```

| Customer | StartDay | EndDay | Product | Cost | 0-30 days | 0-60 days | 0-90 days | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-11 | Cloth | 10.00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-17 | Cloth | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2022-07-05 | 2022-07-09 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-04 | Shoe | 10.00 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| A | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-08 | Shoe | 10.00 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| A | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-03 | Shoe | 10.00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-07 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-07 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2018-05-08 | 2018-05-09 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2018-08-02 | 2018-08-09 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2021-11-09 | 2021-12-09 | Cloth | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2020-06-06 | 2020-06-06 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 2020-07-08 | 2020-07-12 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2020-06-06 | 2020-06-08 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 2020-07-02 | 2020-09-01 | Hat | 10.00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| E | 2020-09-03 | 2020-10-01 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 2020-07-02 | 2020-07-08 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rWf7T9CS)

Comment: Really appreciate Danny!! I learned a lot from you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  Customer    
       ,StartDay    
       ,EndDay  
       ,Product 
       ,Cost
       ,[0] as '0-30 days'
       ,[1] as '30-60 days'
       ,[2] as '60-90 days'
       ,[3] as '90+ days'
from
(
select  t.Customer
       ,t.StartDay
       ,t.EndDay
       ,t.Product
       ,t.Cost
       ,case when (datediff(day, t.EndDay, t2.StartDay)-1)/30 > 3 then 3 else (datediff(day, t.EndDay, t2.StartDay)-1)/30 end as dd
from    t left join t t2 on  t2.Customer = t.Customer 
                         and t2.Product = t.Product
                         and t2.StartDay > t.EndDay
) t
pivot(count(dd) for dd in([0],[1],[2],[3])) p
order by Customer, Product, StartDay
```

| Customer | StartDay | EndDay | Product | Cost | 0-30 days | 30-60 days | 60-90 days | 90+ days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-11 | Cloth | 10.00 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-17 | Cloth | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2022-07-05 | 2022-07-09 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-04 | Shoe | 10.00 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2019-01-07 | 2019-01-08 | Shoe | 10.00 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-03 | Shoe | 10.00 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 2019-03-03 | 2019-03-07 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-07 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2018-05-08 | 2018-05-09 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2018-08-02 | 2018-08-09 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2021-11-09 | 2021-12-09 | Cloth | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2020-06-06 | 2020-06-06 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2020-07-08 | 2020-07-12 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2020-06-06 | 2020-06-08 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 2020-07-02 | 2020-09-01 | Hat | 10.00 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 2020-09-03 | 2020-10-01 | Hat | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| E | 2020-07-02 | 2020-07-08 | Shoe | 10.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4dQMKUJb)

Comment: Thanks Danny. I think I don't describe my needs clearly. Actually I need to check the whole records to summarize all satisfied records, not just one following record.  Is that possible to do it?  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: see updated answer. I added what you wanted and checked the results to make sure they're correct.

Comment: It's exactly what I need for 2nd scenario!! Thanks Danny.  As for 1st scenario, is that possible to do it? The counts in 90 days duration  include the counts in 60 days, and the counts in 60 days include the counts in 30 days.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I added another answer with the solution to the 1st scenario.